# How to check if steepest gradient method will converge?

Tags: linear-programming, nonlinear-optimization, quadratic-programming

So I have this function

$ f(x,y) = x^4 - 2x^2 +x + 4y^2 $

and I want to know if the steepest gradient method will converge if I pick an arbitrary point and apply said method.

My initial thought was to find the Hessian and check if greater than 0, because if so I know this converges to a global optimum but I get

$$
        \begin{bmatrix}
        12x^2 - 4 & 0 &\\
        0 & 8 &\\
        \end{bmatrix}
$$

and I'm not sure what to do next.

How should I go about finding whether the steepest gradient method will converge?

Comment: I dont want to be picky, but you presented an expression rather than an equation...

Comment: fixed - do you have any idea how to do this problem?